# Quieting individual ant tasks

Tags: ant

Is there a way to get individual ant tasks to run quietly? I know of the -q switch, but that applies globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try implementing your own [Ant logger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html).

One idea, using the existing listeners, would be to pipe all output to log4j and then implement a [logging message filter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/StringMatchFilter.html) that suppresses certain log messages

```
ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener
```

The log4j appender configuration would look something like:

```
<appender name=".."  class="..">
    ..
    ..
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">
        <param name="StringToMatch" value="ANT output to suppress" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" />
    </filter>
</appender>
```